# Prevent Sass producing empty files

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm storing all my sass constants in a single **constants.scss**

This file is next to all other scss files I use in my project.

When I run sass thanks a **gulp sass:watch** command priori to my coding session, I have an empty constants.css file produced that come bugging me from a VCS point of view.

Can someone advise me the best way to prevent sass producing this empty file ?

Comment: Rename the file to `_constants.scss`?

Comment: Didn't knew it was possible to designate this way files whose the only goal are to be included. Thanks for the tips ! @anderssonola